# BigDecimal not keeping actual value when being returned from Java method

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I am making a Currency conversion app in Java. Some other awesome StackOverflowians gave me advice to read up on BigDecimal for the purpose of replacing double to fix any precision issues.

I have a two method system; where it converts from the starting currency into USD, then converts the USD value to the destination currency.

Note, my conversion rates are stored like this:

```
// Conversion Rates - START (as of October 30, 2018 @ 3:19 AM)
// Rates obtained from exchange-rates.org

//Convert to United States Dollar rates
private final BigDecimal CAD_TO_USD = new BigDecimal(0.76135);
private final BigDecimal EUR_TO_USD = new BigDecimal(1.1345);
private final BigDecimal YEN_TO_USD = new BigDecimal(0.008853);
// Conversion Rates - END
```

After I replaced my doubles with their respective BigDecimals - I decided to test it and see how it all works out.

My tester class runs the following method to start the conversion process.

```
public BigDecimal convert()
{
    BigDecimal value;

    value = convertToUSD(); //Converts the current currency into USD 
    value = convertFromUSD(value);  //Converts the previous USD currency value into the destination currency

    return value;
}
```

When I enter my sample variables (which are converting 2.78 YEN to Canadian Dollars), I stepped through the process and found that everything functions up until I return a value.

From the earlier mentioned method, `convertToUSD()` is run and is coded as follows

```
private BigDecimal convertToUSD()
{
    switch (fromCurrency)
    {
        case "USD":
            return fromQuantity.multiply(new BigDecimal(1));

        case "CAD":
            return fromQuantity.multiply(CAD_TO_USD);

        case "EUR":
            return fromQuantity.multiply(EUR_TO_USD);

        case "YEN":
            return fromQuantity.multiply(YEN_TO_USD);
    }

    return new BigDecimal(0);
}
```

ALl the values are passed in correctly, it steps through down to the proper case ("YEN"), and the variable pane shows that the "fromQuantity" BigDecimal has a intCompact value of 278 (which makes sense to me)

[image]

As soon as the breakpoint returns back to the "convert" method, it gets all messed up. Instead of returning the `2.78 * 0.008853 = 0.0246`, it returns `-9223372036854775808`.

[image]

This causes all other calculations to produce and error.

I am new to using BigDecimal, so I may be making a complete obvious mistake; but I am happy to learn, so I sought advice from you guys :)

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use the constructor that takes a double. Use the one that takes a String. The double value does not map to BigDecimal like you think it will. not sure it's your only issue here but it gets you off to a bad start.

Comment: The intCompact value of -9223372036854775808 is Long::MIN_VALUE. If it has that value, that means it should not be used to calculate the BigDecimal value and that the BigInteger intVal contains the actual digits of the BigDecimal instead. So although you use doubles to initialize your BigDecimals, their value could be inaccrutate, but should not be too far from the truth. **Anyway, the value in intCompact has no meaning here. That value is merely a flag to disregard intCompact.**. You can check the actual value of the BigDecimal with `System.out.println(value);`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use `String`, not `double` literals.

```
new BigDecimal( "2.78" )           // Pass "2.78" not 2.78
.multiply(
    new BigDecimal( "0.008853" )   // Pass "0.008853" not 0.008853
)
.toString()
```

> 0.02461134

## Do not pass floating-point types

The point of the [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.math.BigInteger)) class is to avoid the [inherent inaccuracies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems) found in [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) technology. Floating-point types such as `float`/`Float` and `double`/`Double` trade away accuracy for speed of execution. In contrast, `BigDecimal` is slow but accurate.

Your code:

```
new BigDecimal( 0.76135 )
new BigDecimal( 1.1345 )
new BigDecimal( 0.008853 )
```

…is passing a `double` primitive literal. During compilation, the text you typed `0.76135` is parsed as a number, specifically as a `double` (a 64-bit floating-point value). At that point you have introduced inaccuracies inherent with this type. In other words, the `double` produced from `0.76135` may no longer be exactly `0.76135`.

Let’s dump your `BigDecimal` instances immediately after instantiating.

```
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( 0.76135 ) );    // Passing a `double` primitive.
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( 1.1345 ) );
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( 0.008853 ) );
```

> 0.7613499999999999712230192017159424722194671630859375
>
> 1.13450000000000006394884621840901672840118408203125
>
> 0.0088529999999999997584154698415659368038177490234375

So, by creating `double` number values, you invoked floating-point technology, and introduced inaccuracies.

## Use strings

The solution? Work with strings, avoiding the `double` type entirely.

Put some **double-quote marks around those inputs**, and *voilà*.

```
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( "0.76135" ) );  // Passing a `String` object.
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( "1.1345" ) );
System.out.println( new BigDecimal( "0.008853" ) );
```

> 0.76135
>
> 1.1345
>
> 0.008853

### Example

You expected `2.78 * 0.008853 = 0.0246`. Let’s try it.

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal( "2.78" );
BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal( "0.008853" );
BigDecimal z = x.multiply( y );
System.out.println( x + " * " + y + " = " + z );
```

> 2.78 * 0.008853 = 0.02461134

Next you should study up on rounding & truncating with `BigDecimal`. Already covered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This accurately explains why the code is wrong, but should explain what to do to fix it as well.

Comment: The point of `BigDecimal` is not that `float` and `double` are inaccurate, but rather that while the latter two use binary arithmetic, `BigDecimal` uses decimal arithmetic, which makes more sense with amounts of money than binary arithmetic.  In general, applying binary arithmetic to numbers intended to be decimals can sometimes lead to unintuitive results, as the `BigDecimal(double)` constructor illustrates.

Comment: @PeterO. “Unintuitive results” = “inaccurate”. While I get your point in the academic sense, at the end of the day, my customer only cares that the invoice is correctly totaled, the paycheck is right, and the ledgers balance.

Comment: @Basil : That was my point: binary and decimal arithmetics should not mix.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are assuming `intCompact` represents a non-floating point version of your float. In some cases, it does, but in most cases it will not.

For example I tried to reduce your problem to the bare minimum.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final BigDecimal YEN_TO_USD = new BigDecimal(0.008853);
    BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(2.78);

    value = value.multiply(YEN_TO_USD);
    System.out.println(value);
  }
}
```

Placing a break on the line with the `println` I get the following:

[image: break point]

You see the `intCompact` is the same as yours (`-9223372036854775808`). But the `stringCache` in this case is the expected value.

Refer to the answer by Basil as to why you should construct BigDecimal using strings and not doubles.